# SparkSQL key not found: scale

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Spark version is 1.6.0.

I trying to do a simple SQL query to the remote Oracle 11g DB by using Spark SQL.

Of course the ojdbc driver is added to the classpath and ping to the DB is also ok.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME).setMaster("yarn-client");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SqlContext sqlContext = new SqlContext(jsc );

Map<String, String> connectionProperties = new HashMap<>();
connectionProperties.put("user", username);
connectionProperties.put("password", password);
connectionProperties.put("url", url);
connectionProperties.put("dbtable", "(SELECT * FROM tableName)");
connectionProperties.put("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

DataFrame result = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(connectionProperties).load();
```

The error arise at the last line at `.load()` method.

The resulted stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: scale
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata.get(Metadata.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata.getLong(Metadata.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.OracleDialect$.getCatalystType(OracleDialect.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at myapp.dfComparator.entity.OriginalSourceTable.load(OriginalSourceTable.java:74)
    at myapp.dfComparator.Program.main(Program.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have no mind, what is wrong.

**EDIT 01/27/2017**

Additional information:

Hadoop version is 2.6.0-cdh.5.8.3

Spark version is 1.6.0 with Scala version 2.10.5

I trying to reproduce the code above in scala and execute it using `spark-shell`:

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@db-host:1521:orcl", 
"dbtable"-> "schema_name.table_name", 
"driver"-> "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", 
"username" -> "user", 
"password" -> "pwd")).load()
```

The result of this code is the similiar stacktrace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: scale
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata.get(Metadata.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata.getLong(Metadata.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.OracleDialect$.getCatalystType(OracleDialect.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:25)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at <init>(<console>:44)
    at .<init>(<console>:48)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

So, I have strong perception that there is some mistakes in configuration of spark or(and) hadoop.

**EDIT 02/01/2017**

I investigate that such problem is arise only in case when the column type in oracle table is `NUMBER`. For example, if I cast the `id` column (which type is `NUMBER`) to `VARCHAR` in select statement, then all will works fine:

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
    Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@db-host:1521:orcl", 
    "dbtable"-> "(SELECT CAST(id AS varchar(3))) FROM tableName", 
    "driver"-> "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", 
    "username" -> "user", 
    "password" -> "pwd")).load()
```

In more detail - the staktrace show us, that problem is appear at `org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata.get` method. By investigate this method from [sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata.scala) we can see (or assume) that in case of `NUMBER` type it trying to cast it to Long and cannot find the scale of it.

Thats why now I think that main issue is in cloudera distr of apache spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time I received the answer from [Cloudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/SparkSQL-key-not-found-scale/m-p/50068/thread-id/2391#M2399) that in CDH 5.8.3 with Spark 1.6 it is a known issue, which is resolved in Spark version 2.0.

For overcoming the problem we have 3 options:

- In select query `CAST` **any numeric** type to `VARCHAR`. Instead of
  `CAST` we also can use `TO_CHAR` function.
- For loading data use RDD/JavaRDD (instead of Dataframe) and after that
  convert it to Dataframes (which is much faster)
- Use CDH 5.9.x